# Display only one entry per category

Tags: categories, expressionengine

I am relatively new to EE and I'm in trouble with categories...

I have this page here:

http://www.nationallighting.ie/testbed/index.php/products

all the products are categorised and divided into boxes so when one box is clicked the div slides to show the category. (so far I've only added a few items, there's 2 in Outdoor category for instance)

Now my problem is that when I click on a single item and I go to the "single product" template

http://www.nationallighting.ie/testbed/index.php/products-single

there is one item for each category listed, whereas I would only like to display the item that I clicked originally, so one item only in the "single product" template.

Here's the EE code for the "single product" template, obviously I am doing something wrong and I can't see what it is!!! Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

```
        <!-- content about inside -->
    <div class="inside products">
    <h3>Product details</h3>
    {exp:channel:categories style="linear" channel="products"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="single_product" category="{category_id}" limit="1"}
    <div class="description">

        <img src="{cat_main_image}" alt="{title}" />
        <div class="descr-inside">
        <h3>Crystal - Sgopera-3ch</h3>
        <p><strong>Description: </strong>3 Light Pendant with glass beads</p>
        <p><strong>Supplier: </strong>Endon</p>
        <p><strong>Width: </strong>455mm</p>
        <p><strong>Height: </strong>695mm</p>
        <p><strong>Lamp Type: </strong>GU10</p>
        <p><strong>Max. Wattage: </strong>3 x 50W</p>
        <p><strong>Energy saving: </strong>yes</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:channel:categories}
    </div> <!-- end of inside -->
```